# Inseparable polynomial in k[x] can be expressed as the pth power of some polynomial in k[x]?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

An irreducible polynomial $f \in k[x]$ is *inseparable* iff $f(x)=g(x^p)$, $g\in k[x]$.

In a field of characteristic $p>0$ Frobenius identity and the fact that $k$ is algebraically closed means we can write $$f(x)=g(x^ p)=h(x)^p,$$ where $h$ is obtained by replacing all coefficients of $g$ by their $p$th roots. How do you infer this?

Is this true for some $f \in k[x_1,...,x_n]$?

Thanks in advance.
This is from Klaus Hulek, pages 34, 35.

Comment: How would you define when a polynomial is separable in the case of multiple variables? You can not simply cut off linear factors, can you?

Comment: If the formal derivative of f wrt xi is non zero then f is seperable wrt xi.

Comment: Are you looking for a single coordinate result, i.e. something like
> If the derivative of $f$ wrt $x_i$ is zero, then $f(x_1,...,x_n) = g(x_1,...,x_i^p,...,x_n)$,

or do you aim for a complete result, something like
> If the derivative of $f$ with respect to $x_i$ is zero for all $i$, then $f(x_1,...,x_n) = g(x_1^p,x_2^p,...,x_n^p)$ ?

Comment: I am actually trying to deduce the second sentence. Specifically how does frobenius identity and algebraically closedness of k imply the result? Sorry if this is obvious, I can't get it for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll do the case $n=2$ and you can then generalize it:

Let $f \in k[x,y]$ and assume that both the derivative with respect to $x$ and with respect to $y$ are zero. We can write
$$f(x,y) = \sum_{i=0}^n f_i(y)x^i$$
for some $f_i \in k[y]$. The derivative with respect to $x$ is then
$$\sum_{i=0}^n i f_i(y)x^{i-1}.$$
This is zero if and only if $i$ is zero whenever $f_i$ is not the zero polynomial. Hence, we can conclude that the exponents of $x$ are always multiples of $p$.

The same goes for $f(x,y) = \sum_{j=0}^m h_j(x)y^j$ for some $h_j \in k[x]$ and thus also the exponents of $y$ are always multiples of $p$.

Btw. I don't see where one should need $k$ to be algebraically closed, the characteristic is the important point.